# How to present a particular SQL queried row as columns in output

Tags: sql

I need to present the attached output in PIC1 as the result in PIC2. The query used for generating PIC1 output in SQLDeveloper:

```
select subs_nm, as_of_date, run_status, (select max (tp.pr_vl)
from ual_mng.tqueue tq, ual_mng.tparams tp, ual_mng.tstatus ts 
WHERE tq.tid = tp.tid AND tq.tid = ts.tid and tq.run_id = pcm.run_id and tp.pr_nm in ('TOT_RECORD_CNT')) as RECORD_COUNT 
from UAL_MNG.PCM_SUBS_RUN_DTL_VW pcm where SUBS_NM='S_TS2_AQUA_A1_RLAP_DL' and AS_OF_DATE in ('2021-09-01','2021-09-02') order by run_start_dtm desc;
```

Appreciate all help.

[image: PIC1]
[image: PIC2]

Comment: PIVOTing a table _can_ be done in SQL, but it's often a bad idea which causes no-end of problems. This is because SQL is a tuple (row)-oriented query-language, it is not a _presentation language_ - and pivoting a table is a _presentation concern_. If you're generating a business report then you should pivot the table in your reporting system, not in SQL. If your reporting system doesn't support pivoting then you've got much bigger problems to worry about...

Comment: Hi Dai, Thanks for responding. 
The query is part of the shell script, which is aimed to i) fetch data from DB in csv format ii) parse through the data to prepare the reporting table over mail using HTML.

I am assuming when you are referring to "bad-idea", it is related to resource crunch & DB locks while processing the data. The standard output will range between 50-80 rows with multiple subscriptions instead of just one as shown in PIC1.

Comment: If at all, you could suggest on how to achieve PIC2 result with query, with considered issues, it'll be really helpful!!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't need it to be dynamic (ie. it will only be two columns and you know which two months they are) you can do

```
select subs_nm,
       max(case when as_of_date = '2021-09-01' then RECORD_COUNT else 0 end) as SEP1, 
       max(case when as_of_date = '2021-09-02' then RECORD_COUNT else 0 end) as SEP2,
from (
-- Your query
)
group by subs_nm
```

You can work out the percentage difference using the same expressions.

nb. I would always use an explicit date format mask.   This might not run on a different machine / software.    So use `to_date('2021-09-01', 'yyyy-mm-dd')`

Comment: Hi Jameson, Thank you for responding. Actually the query is a part of a shell script used to fetch data for subscriptions and accordingly prepare report using HTML tags in the script itself.

Comment: select subs_nm,
       max(case when as_of_date='2021-09-01' then TO_CHAR(RECORD_COUNT) else 0 end) as SEP1, 
       max(case when as_of_date='2021-09-02' then TO_CHAR(RECORD_COUNT) else 0 end) as SEP2
from (
--My_query)
group by subs_nm;

GETTING BELOW ERROR

ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected CHAR got NUMBER
00932. 00000 -  "inconsistent datatypes: expected %s got %s"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 18 Column: 78

Comment: select subs_nm,
       max(case when as_of_date=TO_CHAR('2021-09-01', yyyy-mm-dd) then TO_CHAR(RECORD_COUNT) else 0 end) as SEP1, 
       max(case when as_of_date=TO_CHAR('2021-09-02', yyyy-mm-dd) then TO_CHAR(RECORD_COUNT) else 0 end) as SEP2
from (
--My_query)
group by subs_nm;

TO FIX THAT ADDED TO_CHAR BUT GETTING BELOW ERROR 

ORA-00904: "DD": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 3 Column: 63

Comment: Hi Jameson, I made a few tweaks and it worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Posting the query, which worked in the script :

```
 select subs_nm, SEP1, SEP2, round((((SEP1-SEP2)/SEP1)*100),2) as DIFF_PER from ( select subs_nm, 
    max(case when as_of_date='2021-09-01' then RECORD_COUNT else '0' end) as SEP1,
    max(case when as_of_date='2021-09-02' then RECORD_COUNT else '0' end) as SEP2 from (-- *Main Query*);
```